# Python: Keyboard events not propagated from wx.html2.WebView widget to dialog

Tags: python, html, windows, wxpython

In Python 3.10.5 on Windows 11 employing the wxPython 4.2.0 package, I am using the `wx.html2.WebView` widget to display HTML content in a help dialog. Now, I want the dialog to close based on the Escape key press event. However, if I bind the `wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK` event handlerr to the dialog object, the event does not get propagated  and thus the handler is not executed when the keyboard focus is on the WebView widget, but if the focus is on other widget in the dialog, such as a close button I added there next to the WebView  widget, the event is received properly. To better demonstrate it, here is the code I am using:

```
class HelpHTMLDialog(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super(HelpHTMLDialog, self).__init__(parent=parent, title=title, size=(1000, 800))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.charHook)

        self.addWidgets()
        self.Centre()
        self.ShowModal()

    def addWidgets(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # HTML browser containing the help page
        self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self.panel)
        html = "<p>Hello there! <a href='#'>Click me</a>.</p>"
        self.browser.SetPage(html, "")
        vbox.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        # Close button
        self.closeButton = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Close")
        self.closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onCloseButtonClick)
        vbox.Add(self.closeButton, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)

    def close(self):
        self.Destroy()

    def charHook(self, event):
        key = event.GetKeyCode()
        if key == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            self.close()
        else:
            event.Skip()

    def onCloseButtonClick(self, event):
        self.close()
```

The question therefore is - How can the key press or charhook event be propagated from the WebView widget to the dialog so that I can handle it? I also tried binding the event to the WebView widget instead of the dialog object, but that had the same effect.

Comment: On Linux this works, so the suspect looks like the `WebViewBackend` which you can override or the platform itself. On Linux the event can be bound to `self`, `self.browser` or `self.closeButton`, all work equally well.

Comment: I've tried `self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self.panel, backend=wx.html2.WebViewBackendEdge)`, having the handler bbound both on self and self.browser, but with no success.

Comment: Check https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/ms-edge-backend-for-webview/34953 and there appears to be build instructions for `WEBVIEW_BACKEND_EDGE` @ https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.html2.WebView.html?highlight=webview I can't be more help because I dumped Microsoft as a bad job 20 years ago.

Comment: I am able to use the Edge backend without a problem, but the issue with key events being not propagated from the HTML browser still persists with Edge backend.